# Testing React-Bootstrap-Multiselect with Mocha

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, mocha.js, enzyme

When I try to test the npm module `react-bootstrap-multiselect` with `mocha` and `enzyme`, I get the following error:

```
if (typeof jQuery.fn.dropdown !=="undefined" return jQuery;
TypeError: Cannot read property 'dropdown' of undefined
```

this error happens in `\react-bootstrap-multiselect\lib\bootstrap-dropdown`. My code up to the point of error is:

```
import React from 'react';
import { mount } from 'enzyme';
import { expect } from 'chai';
import jsdom from 'jsdom';

const doc = jsdom.jsdom('<!doctype html><html><body></body></html>')
global.document = doc
global.window = doc.defaultView
global.$ = global.jQuery = require('jquery')(global.window);

import MasterTable from '../components/masterTable';
```

where the error is thrown when I try to import `MasterTable`. MasterTable tries to render the `react-bootstrap-multiselect`.

Answer (score 0):

After `global.window = doc.defaultView` try adding:

```
global.navigator = window.navigator
```